# Remove all Leading zero from first column and if all zero found then Preserved 1 zero

Tags: unix, scripting, sh

I want to remove leading Zero from first column and if all Zeros are found in first column then 1 Zero should be preserved.

```
00123|a 
00154|b 
00000|c
```

*Output*

```
123|a 
154|b 
0|c
```

Comment: What code are using to do this , please add  it

Comment: I am using sed s/^0*(\d+)$/$1/ but through this code all the Zeros are removed I want to preserv one Zero if all Zero found.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }  # set field separators
{ $1+=0 }             # add a zero to remove leading zeros
1' file               # output
```

Output:

```
123|a 
154|b 
0|c
```

Here's one that works for integers:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
{ $1=sprintf("%.0f",$1) }  # %.0f will round off decimals
1' file
```

Output:

```
123|a 
154|b 
0|c
4295229012|0
```

Comment: Above code is working fine, if first Digit is less than 11 Digit, i have a number like 004295229012|0 will be converted to 4.29523e+09|0 using above code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use sed :

```
sed 's/^0*//;s/^|/0|/' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string="0000123456000" 
echo $((10#$string))
```

Comment: it's working but i have file with which contains n number of records. I want to preform above Operation only on first column

Comment: column you mean instead of "00123|a"
it will be "00123                  a" ?

Comment: I have a pipe separated  file, and I want to leading Zero from only first column and only zeros then one Zero should be preserved.  00123|a will be 123|a and 00000|b will be 0|b